# lxml XPath search with two conditions

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

My XML file is:

```
<releases>
    <release id="1">
        <title>Title1</title>
        <formats>
            <format name="CD" qty="2" text="">
            </format>
        </formats>
        <released>2016-02-00</released>
    </release>
    <release id="2">
        <title>Title2</title>
        <formats>
            <format name="LP" qty="2" text="">
            </format>
        </formats>
        <released>2018-03-00</released>
    </release>
    <release id="3">
        <title>Title3</title>
        <formats>
            <format name="CD" qty="1" text="">
            </format>
        </formats>
        <released>1995-01-15</released>
    </release>  
</releases>
```

In Python3, I want to find the release IDs where the "format" name = "CD" and the "released" text contains text "1995" (so release id 3 should be the result)

I have this code which finds the CD releases, and prints the release dates:

```
for rls in root.findall(".//format[@name='CD']....//released"):
    print (rls.tag, rls.attrib, rls.text)
```

And I also have this code which finds all the releases with "1995" and prints the date of the first result:

```
print (root.xpath("/releases/release/released[contains(text(),'1995')]")[0].text)
```

I'm having trouble finding how to combine both (also I'm using `findall` in one, and `xpath` in the other, not pretty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the conditions in the predicate portion of a selector in XPath.  The following tells XPath to:

- return all `release` nodes, that contain:

  - a `format` node with the attribute of `name=CD` *and*
  - a `released` node with text that has `1995` in in

```py
xml.xpath("./release[.//format[@name='CD'] and .//released[contains(text(),'1995')]]/@id")
# returns:
['3']
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great on a 2GB xml file. Running it on a 55GB file, RAM (32GB) and swap space (another 32GB) get used up in 5 minutes and the python script ends with "Killed". Is there a way to free-up memory as it goes, or a less memory intensive way? If not, I will split the file up into chunks and do one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```xml
/releases/release[formats/format/@name='CD'][starts-with(released,'1995')]
```

will select those `release` elements in `CD` format whose `released` date starts with `1995`,

```
<release id="3">
    <title>Title3</title>
    <formats>
        <format name="CD" qty="1" text="">
        </format>
    </formats>
    <released>1995-01-15</released>
</release>
```

as requested.

You mentioned wanting the `id` attributes.  If you actually do want to iterate over all such `id` attributes rather than the elements themselves, simply append `/@id` to the above XPath.